# How do I change the output of the serialization from my entity?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, serialization

```
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
//            $normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(2);
$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
    return $object->getId();
});
$normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('users', '__initializer__', '__cloner__', 'authkey', '__isInitialized__', "products"));
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array(new JsonEncoder()));

return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($product, 'json'));
```

Thats the result:

```
{
  "id": 128,
  "name": "product",
  "price": 12,
  "category": {
    "id": 58,
    "name": "category",
    "company": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "foo",
      "tables": []
    }
  },
  "description": "this is a product",
  "company": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "tables": []
  }
}
```

but how can i get the following result:

```
{
  "id": 128,
  "name": "product",
  "price": 12,
  "category": {
    "name": "category"
  },
  "description": "this is a product",
  "company": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "tables": []
  }
}
```

How can I variate between the values?

for example I want here:

> "category": {
>       "name": "category"   },

later the id as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the serializer component [Attributes Groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups). I believe this is what you are looking for.

You can select which entity properties should be included in each particular response.

Just simply set group in an entity

```
/**
 * @Groups({"group1", "group2"})
 */
public $foo;
```

And then specify group or an array of groups for serialization

```
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer));    
$data = $serializer->normalize($obj, null, array('groups' => 'group1'));
```

Sometimes just groups is not enough, that is when you can use [Doctrine hydrator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md). This is a bit more complex solution, but this gives you much more possibilities.

Normally you would use `Attributes Groups` when you need to make a simple selection - retrieve one particular entity or a collection of entities with some joined entities (use groups for joins as well). `Doctrine hydrator` is used when you need an aggregated selection, for example retrieve data from table that does not has specified relation, or add combined data along with regular data.